# How can I get ruby's "Date.end_of_week(:monday)" method to work with a fixnum? e.g. "Date.end_of_week(1)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date

How can I get ruby's "Date.end_of_week(:monday)" method to work with a fixnum?  e.g. "Date.end_of_week(1)".

If I try it (i.e. ) I get

> TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum

```
1.9.3p0 :001 > start_date = Time.now.to_date
 => Sat, 03 Mar 2012 
1.9.3p0 :002 > start_date.end_of_week
 => Sun, 04 Mar 2012 
1.9.3p0 :003 > start_date.end_of_week(1)
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

That is the day will be dynamic, so I'll end up with the user selecting the day, which I can allocate to a fixnum based on the Date's constant

> DAYS_INTO_WEEK    =   { :monday => 0, :tuesday => 1, :wednesday => 2,
>   :thursday => 3, :friday => 4, :saturday => 5, :sunday => 6 }

Comment: Can you not use Time.now.beginning_of_week + DAYS_INTO_WEEK[:sunday].day

Comment: you have ":sunday" as input whereas I want to use a variable as input (e.g. 2) which the user selects from a drop down

Comment: Then you can directly do Time.now.beginning_of_week + 2.send(:days). But you have to ensure checks to see you are receiving integers form the view and the integers are within weekday ranges

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the quickest way but I've done this:

```
DAY_TO_SYMBOL = {0 => :monday, 1 => :tuesday, 2 => :wednesday, 3 => :thursday, 4 => :friday, 5 => :saturday, 6 => :sunday}

we_end_day = << depends on user imput >>
start_date.end_of_week(DAY_TO_SYMBOL[we_end_day])
```